# From treeview to simple array

Tags: php, recursion, treeview

I have a multidimensional array (tree view) and I am trying to create a simple array from that.

Example of tree view array:

```
$arr = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'children' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => 3
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

What I am trying to, is getting an array with ID as key and parentID as value.

Example:

```
$arr = [
    1 => 0,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 2
];
```

Comment: Add a bit of what you have tried, so that we can help you get solved!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I solved the problem:

```
$result = [];
function recur($arr, $parent = 0) {
    global $result;

    foreach ($arr as $x ) {

        $result[$x['id']] = $parent;
        if (isset($x['children'])) {
            recur($x['children'], $x['id']);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

recur($arr);
```

Comment: With that global variable you are asking for race conditions

Comment: Can you help me with better solution?

Comment: @YackY Please check the answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function relation($parent, $child, &$result)
{
    if($child['children']) {
        $result[$child['id']] = $parent;
        relation($child['id'], $child['children'], $result);
    }else{
        $result[$child['id']] = $parent;
    }
}

$arr1 = array('id'=>3);
$arr2 = array('id'=>2, 'children'=>$arr1);
$arr3 = array('id'=>1, 'children' => $arr2);
$result = array();

relation(0, $arr3, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: From what I see here, instead of using global variable I should pass the variable by reference?

Comment: @YackY I think in recursion best way is to use the by reference. And about your code when i execute it, it is not giving the correct output. You can test your code with my input.